# DynamoDB - Delete Item based on ConditionExpression on Sort Key

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to delete records from dynamodb based on PrimaryKey and `ConditionExpression` on SortKey?

Following code sample is throwing an exception for me

```
 DeleteVideoCall = async function (pk, sk) {
    let params = {
        TableName: this._tableName,
        Key: {
            pk: { S: pk.toString() },
            sk: { S: sk.toString() }
        },
        ConditionExpression: "begins_with(sk,:sk)",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":sk" : { S: sk.toString() + "_" }
        }
    };

    return this._ddb
        .deleteItem(params)
        .promise()
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(`Video Call '${pk}/${sk}' deleted`);
            return null;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(
                `Error deleting video room '${pk}/${sk}' (${error})`
            );
            throw error;
        });
};
```

I want to delete all records that `begins_with` sk and *. For example if sk is 560622 then delete all records where sk begins_with 560622*

with the code above I get this error:

> Error deleting video room '10900/560622'
> (ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. You need whole key to perform a delete. What you can do:

- query items (limit retrieved properties to your PK and SK)
- use batch-write to remove multiple items, it also accepts delete requests